# Hikari CP Giving Communication Failure Link Error,where as Plain JDBC Connection is working

Tags: java, hikaricp

Scenario:Opening and Initializing Connection Pool with Hikari CP.
Status:Communication link failure zero packet received from server.
Target Server:MYSQL 5.6.31-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
Driver Lib:compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
Hikari CP:compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '3.1.0'

Plain JDBC Connection without using Hikari CP is working fine.

Question:What is it I am doing wrong?
Things tried:changed ideltimeout and maxlifetime to one minute less than default value of maxtimewait out sql server.Same issue persists.
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/FAQ

```
DbConnectionHolder connectionHolder = new DbConnectionHolder();
        HikariConfig tranasctionDbConfig = new HikariConfig();
        HikariConfig configDb = new HikariConfig();

        tranasctionDbConfig.setDriverClassName(dbConfigHolder.getDriverClassName());
        tranasctionDbConfig.setJdbcUrl(dbConfigHolder.getTransactionDbUrl());
        tranasctionDbConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        // tranasctionDbConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(5000);
        //tranasctionDbConfig.setConnectionTimeout(2000);
        tranasctionDbConfig.setIdleTimeout(28740000);
        tranasctionDbConfig.setMaxLifetime(28740000);

        tranasctionDbConfig.setUsername(dbConfigHolder.getTransactionDbUserName());
        tranasctionDbConfig.setPassword(dbConfigHolder.getTransactionDbPassword());

        configDb.setDriverClassName(dbConfigHolder.getDriverClassName());
        configDb.setJdbcUrl(dbConfigHolder.getConfigDbUrl());

        configDb.setIdleTimeout(28740000);
        configDb.setMaxLifetime(28740000);


        configDb.setUsername(dbConfigHolder.getConfigDbUserName());
        configDb.setPassword(dbConfigHolder.getConfigDbPassword());

        //configDb.setIdleTimeout(200000);
    //  configDb.setMaxLifetime(200000);

    DataSource configDataSource = new HikariDataSource(configDb);

        DataSource transactionDatasource = new HikariDataSource(tranasctionDbConfig);

        connectionHolder.setConfigDataSource(configDataSource);
        connectionHolder.setTranctionDataSource(transactionDatasource);
        return connectionHolder;
```

Comment: Please show the literal values for the driver class and URL used when connecting with Hikari and when connecting directly. Also post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: It was url issue.class path was picking different dbconfig file.Thanks for ur response

Comment: Your maxLifetime likely exceeds either the DB native timeout or timeout in the infrastructure between the app and the DB (firewall, load-balancer, etc.).  Try a very short maxLifetime, like 2 minutes (120000ms).  If the error goes away, you know that is the issue, and you can investigate what the exact appropriate value should be.